# Sending "content-type" as "application/json" via XMLHttpRequest() to a Google Cloud Function is causing a KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, content-type

I have a JavaScript app in an html file that I'm using to send requests to a Google Cloud Function. This works as intended and the cloud function is triggered. I am currently doing `xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` to send the data which also works as intended. However, I'm only using urlencoded to send the data because when I trying setting the content-type to application/json, Google Cloud Functions throws the following error:

```
KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'
```

I am especially confused because when I trigger the function from a local python script using content-type = application/json, it works just fine. I've looked up several guides on how to call a GCF using XMLHttpRequest() going so far as to simply copy paste others' code and swap out the GCF url with mine and the issue still occurs.

What am I missing? Is there some setting withing Google Cloud that I need to change? Some limitation or special setting on XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

I was not setting up [CORS response](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors#functions_http_cors-python) in my Google Cloud Function which is necessary when submitting a request via XMLHttpRequest() from a webpage hosted on a different server.